# How to implement min, max, required and optional on an Axis2 web service using Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, wsdl, apache-axis, axis

How can I set the min, max, required and optional attributes of request parameters in an Axis2 web service? I'm using Eclipse and Axis2 to build my web service as such the wsdl file is automatically generated.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to write your interface(WSDL) first and generate the server stub from the WSDL. In WSDL, you can enforce min, max and all other constraints by using Document/Literal format. Put all your constraints in  under  section.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried using wsdl2java (databinding is set to ADB) and then convert it to web service using the create web service tool in Eclipse. However the value of the minOccurs and maxOccurs were not applied on the newly generated web service. When I viewed the wsdl of the generated Axis2 web service, the value of minOccurs is always 0 and no maxOccurs is shown except if its value is unbounded. Also the optional was stripped on the new wsdl. My binding style is already set to document.